# Up to what time administrative staff is available in the college?

Tags: sentence-construction

1) Up to what time administrative staff are/is available in the college?

2) what time up to college administrative staff is available/present in the college?

Which one is correct?

Comment: "Up to what time **are the** administrative staff available **at** the college?"

Answer (score 1):

As Mark Hubbard mentions in his comment:

> "Up to what time are the administrative staff available at the college?"

is the correct grammar for this sentence.  However a more natural way to ask this question would be to refer to the office hours and not just the staff.  Something like:

> What are the hours Administration is open?
>
> Until what time is the Administration office open?
>
> What time does the Administration office close?

If the office hours are different from the time the staff are actually *available*, you can ask:

> When are the Administration staff available?
>
> What are the hours that the Administration staff are available?